# form php attachment - specify which info I want to show in mail

Tags: php, forms, attachment

I have this code that works good, but when i send it in the mail also appears things that I don't want that appears, for example:

> submit = Enviar
>
> recaptcha_challenge_field =
> 03AHJ_VuuCrxaVdxnIIg-Us7zrqZBDMBXeOuU21J60IblOCtFTQhMgtx-TsfsY6oHl5xbgdeqIRUQ7bTui
>
> recaptcha_response_field = rsinmBlockquote

So I want to ask if there is a way of especify wich items I want to send something like:

```
$body="Contacto:

Nombre: " .$_POST["nombre"] . "\n
Empresa: " .$_POST["empresa"] . "\n
Ubicacion: " .$_POST["ubicacion"] . "\n
Telefono: " .$_POST["telefono"] . "\n
```

I'm not a programmer so I don't know how to put it into the actual code that is working:

```
 function form_mail($sPara, $sAsunto, $sTexto, $sDe)
{
$bHayFicheros = 0;
$sCabeceraTexto = "";
$sAdjuntos = "";


if ($sDe)$sCabeceras = "From:".$sDe."\n";
else $sCabeceras = "";
$sCabeceras .= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
foreach ($_POST as $sNombre => $sValor)
$sTexto = $sTexto."\n".$sNombre." = ".$sValor;

foreach ($_FILES as $vAdjunto)
{
if ($bHayFicheros == 0)
{
$bHayFicheros = 1;
$sCabeceras .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed;";
$sCabeceras .= "boundary=\"--_Separador-de-mensajes_--\"\n";

$sCabeceraTexto = "----_Separador-de-mensajes_--\n";
$sCabeceraTexto .= "Content-type: text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$sCabeceraTexto .= "Content-transfer-encoding: 7BIT\n";

$sTexto = $sCabeceraTexto.$sTexto;
}
if ($vAdjunto["size"] > 0)
{
$sAdjuntos .= "\n\n----_Separador-de-mensajes_--\n";
$sAdjuntos .= "Content-type: ".$vAdjunto["type"].";name=\"".$vAdjunto["name"]."\"\n";;
$sAdjuntos .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64\n";
$sAdjuntos .= "Content-disposition: attachment;filename=\"".$vAdjunto["name"]."\"\n\n";

$oFichero = fopen($vAdjunto["tmp_name"], 'r');
$sContenido = fread($oFichero, filesize($vAdjunto["tmp_name"]));
$sAdjuntos .= chunk_split(base64_encode($sContenido));
fclose($oFichero);
}
}

if ($bHayFicheros)
$sTexto .= $sAdjuntos."\n\n----_Separador-de-mensajes_----\n";
return(mail($sPara, $sAsunto, $sTexto, $sCabeceras, '-faltitux@altitux.mx'));
}

        /*  enviando correo */
        if (form_mail("mymail@mail.com", $_POST[asunto],
"Los datos introducidos en el formulario son:\n\n", $_POST[email]))
$resultMenuUrlName = "bolsa_gracias.html";
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=0;URL=$resultMenuUrlName>";

  } else {
        echo "Lo sentimos pero no ha colocado el texto correctamente! Intente nuevamente...";
  }
```

thx in advice and sorry for the bad english

Comment: you loop through all the posted fields, be selective, and use only the ones you need

Comment: I use only the ones I need, but can't delete the info that it sends about the recaptcha or the submit button, so I want to know if there is a way to hide them and the only thing that i thought is do that of especify wich items appears in the mail or then how those specific ones

Comment: `foreach ($_POST as $sNombre => $sValor) ..` you take all the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

remove

```
foreach ($_POST as $sNombre => $sValor)
$sTexto = $sTexto."\n".$sNombre." = ".$sValor;
```

in the same spot add:

```
$sTexto="Contacto:

Nombre: " .$_POST["nombre"] . "\n
Empresa: " .$_POST["empresa"] . "\n
Ubicacion: " .$_POST["ubicacion"] . "\n
Telefono: " .$_POST["telefono"] . "\n
```

Comment: it works perfectly, thx a lot, a simply thing but for the no programmers is hard to know how to do hehe, gracias!